# Create multiple consumers in Kafka in command line

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm new in Kafka. When I was running the quick start example in command line, I found I can't create multiple consumers in command line.

Condition:

I built a topic named test with 3 partitions, and I also built a producer on this topic.

Then I wanted to create two different consumers sharing a same consumer-group named test1 on this topic.

I ran the command like below twice:

```
   bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test --group test1
```

The first one worked but when I ran the second time the first one would disconnect and the second one worked.

So how can I create two or more consumers in a same consumer group in command line?

```
    WARN Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1146)
```

Comment: Not quite an answer to your question... but you can run the command without any arguments to get help on the command.  Perhaps that might shed some light on the problem.

Comment: But if you can get it to work, you'll have to specify which partitions are read by which clients as you can't have two clients in the same group reading from the same partition.

Comment: the zookeeper port or host  you are using must be probably not up and runnning.

Answer (score 21):

Besides using `--consumer.config` option like the secfree's answer, you can also use

> `--consumer-property group.id=your_group`

option to specify a group name without editing the config file.

Answer (score 18):

1. Default, `kafka-console-consumer.sh` will create a random group.
2. If you want to specify the group name, you can:

   1. Add `group.id=group_name` to a local file `filename`
   2. Use `--consumer.config filename` option of `kafka-console-consumer.sh` to set group
3. You can check your groups at zookeeper's `/consumers/` directory.

Refer: [kafka/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/9d71489ff0e62fd1897c7a6f54671673db7b37b8/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the below command to create the consumers in the group "test-consumer-group" to "test" topic:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server <brokerIP>:9092 --topic test --consumer-property group.id=test-consumer-group
```

Below command will list the consumer group configuration:

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <brokerIP>:9092 --describe --group test-consumer-group
```

Eg:

```
GROUP || TOPIC || PARTITION || CURRENT-OFFSET || LOG-END-OFFSET || LAG      || OWNER
test-consumer-group || test || 0 || 10 || 10 || 0 || consumer-1_/10.210.223.170
```

Comment: for which version of kafka is this used for, this is not working for me of 0.9.0.1 version kafka

Comment: this is with kafka_2.11-0.9.0.1 , what error you see?

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
--partition <Integer: partition>        The partition to consume from.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you consume Topic without groupid Kafka create random groupid for your session. 
You can  specify groupid --consumer-property group.id=test-consumer-group if groupid exist
  or
you can add to your session new groupid(name) when you consume if group not exist 
--topic second-topic --group my-first-group p
and Kafka will create new group