# How can we run multiple kafka consumers through command line?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am testing kafka performance through the shell script they already provided in the kafka package. I have created a topic with 10 partitions and pumping data as shown below:

```
./bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic test-topic --num-records 9000000 --record-size 300 --throughput 250000 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=110.17.14.302:9092 acks=1 max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=1 batch.size=5000
```

Now I want to consume the data which I am pumping as shown above from multiple consumers not just from single consumer. So I started using `kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh`.  This is what I was doing:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test-topic --group test1
```

Is there any way by which we can run multiple kafka consumers in a single consumer group through command line and each of those consumers working on different partitions using `kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh`? I am working with Kafka version `0.10.1.0`

I saw this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289518/create-multiple-consumers-in-kafka-in-command-line) but it doesn't say where to configure how many consumers we want to run and what partition they will work on?

**Update:**

This is the error I saw:

```
./bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --zookeeper 110.27.14.10:2181 --messages 50 --topic test-topic --threads 1

[2017-01-11 22:34:09,785] WARN [ConsumerFetcherThread-perf-consumer-14195_kafka-cluster-3098529006-zeidk-1484174043509-46a51434-2-0], Error in fetch kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread$FetchRequest@54fb48b6 (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:335)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:93)
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.readCompletely(BlockingChannel.scala:129)
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.receive(BlockingChannel.scala:120)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:99)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:83)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:132)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:132)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:132)
        at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply$mcV$sp(SimpleConsumer.scala:131)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:131)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer$$anonfun$fetch$1.apply(SimpleConsumer.scala:131)
        at kafka.metrics.KafkaTimer.time(KafkaTimer.scala:33)
        at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.fetch(SimpleConsumer.scala:130)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.fetch(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:109)
        at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.fetch(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:29)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.processFetchRequest(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:118)
        at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:103)
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:63)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just run the same command (i.e., `./bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh`) multiple times in different consoles.

About partition assignment: Kafka will so this automatically for you. If you use consumer groups.

If you want to do manual partition assignment, you cannot use consumer groups. For this, you cannot use kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh but need to write your own.

Read JavaDoc here: https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: Thanks.. When I ran this command `./bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --zookeeper 110.27.14.10:2181 --messages 50 --topic test-topic --threads 1`.. I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. But on the same box my producer performance test is working fine and I checked memory is not full as well. Added in my question with full stacktrace. Any idea what is wrong or I need to pass some extra parameters which I am missing?

Comment: Not sure, but you can edit kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh to increase the JVM heap space if required.

Comment: I found this jira `https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4491`. Not sure whether it is related and they are saying need to uncomment some ssl stuff?

Comment: Maybe the ticket you mention is related... Not familiar with SSL stuff. About heap space, just open the file and adjust the JVM heap space setting... the file is just 5 lines... (and/or search the internet for Java Heap Space setting -- not part of this question)

Comment: Editing JVMP heap space:  FYI, the consumer perf test defaults to 512MB. I'd simply try increasing the max heap usage by setting the environment variable `KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS` to, say, 1GB via `export KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx1024M"` prior to running the script.